# HTML field will not POST to PHP via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I started to use a base start for PHP login script for my application, cloned from [here](https://github.com/fethica/PHP-Login). When attempting to add elements on the signup page, **signup.php** the data is not being passed to PHP after being processed by AJAX. I am very familiar with PHP, AJAX is a different story -- I am a novice.

I added a POST parser to output to the main signup page, seeing what is being received by PHP. All other inputs are being received except the one I added. As evidenced by the error:

`Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\loader\login\createuser.php on line 11`

[image: Evidence of the issue]

As you can see here, the POST results are displayed below the popup, i wanted to see what was being POSTed to the createuser.php. Clearly the name element I added is not being routed to the proper PHP file. Of course the error displayed by PHP explains that name can't be found due to it not being POSTed.

**signup.php**, the line added is   `<input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="John Smith" autofocus>`. In the end of the file I added a verification to ensure that the form was filled out before posting it to signup.js. **I don't believe the issue to be on this php file.**

```
  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
      session_start();
      session_destroy();
  }


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Signup</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">

      <form class="form-signup" id="usersignup" name="usersignup" method="post" action="createuser.php">
        <h2 class="form-signup-heading">Register</h2>
        <input name="newuser" id="newuser" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus>
    <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="John Smith" autofocus>
        <input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
<br>
        <input name="password1" id="password1" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        <input name="password2" id="password2" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Repeat Password">

        <button name="Submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign up</button>

        <div id="message"></div>
      </form>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <script src="js/signup.js"></script>


    <script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>

$( "#usersignup" ).validate({
  rules: {
    name: {
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        email: true,
        required: true
    },
    password1: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 4
    },
    password2: {
      equalTo: "#password1"
    }
  }
});
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**signup.js**, **This is where I believe the issue to be.** Most likely because I do not understand AJAX. The only thing I changed here was the clause in the IF statement and at the end of the data object, `&name="+name`. Even after adding this to post to createuser.php, PHP isn't receiving the variable.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

  $("#submit").click(function(){

    var username = $("#newuser").val();
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var password = $("#password1").val();
    var password2 = $("#password2").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();

    if((username == "") || (name == "") || (password == "") || (email == "")) {
      $("#message").html("<div class=\"alert alert-danger alert-dismissable\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>Please ensure that name, username and password are all filled.</div>");
    }
    else {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "createuser.php",
        data: "newuser="+username+&password1="+password+"&password2="+password2+"&email="+email+"&name="+name,
        success: function(html){

            var text = $(html).text();
            //Pulls hidden div that includes "true" in the success response
            var response = text.substr(text.length - 4);

          if(response == "true"){

            $("#message").html(html);

                    $('#submit').hide();
            }
        else {
            $("#message").html(html);
            $('#submit').show();
            }
        },
        beforeSend: function()
        {
          $("#message").html("<p class='text-center'><img src='images/ajax-loader.gif'></p>")
        }
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

**createuser.js** I don't believe the issue to be in this PHP file, but I have been wrong before. I added `$name = $_POST['name'];` and I added:

```
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
  echo "{$key} = {$value}\r\n";
```

```
<?php
require 'includes/functions.php';
include_once 'config.php';

//Pull username, generate new ID and hash password
$newid = uniqid(rand(), false);
$newuser = $_POST['newuser'];
$newpw = password_hash($_POST['password1'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$pw1 = $_POST['password1'];
$pw2 = $_POST['password2'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
    //Enables moderator verification (overrides user self-verification emails)
if (isset($admin_email)) {

    $newemail = $admin_email;

} else {

    $newemail = $_POST['email'];

}
//Validation rules
if ($pw1 != $pw2) {

    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>Password fields must match</div><div id="returnVal" style="display:none;">false</div>';

} elseif (strlen($pw1) < 4) {

    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>Password must be at least 4 characters</div><div id="returnVal" style="display:none;">false</div>';

} elseif (!filter_var($newemail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == true) {

    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>Must provide a valid email address</div><div id="returnVal" style="display:none;">false</div>';

} else {
    //Validation passed
    if (isset($_POST['newuser']) && !empty(str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['newuser'])) && isset($_POST['password1']) && !empty(str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['password1']))) {

        //Tries inserting into database and add response to variable

        $a = new NewUserForm;

        $response = $a->createUser($newuser, $newid, $newemail, $newpw);

        //Success
        if ($response == 'true') {

            echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>'. $signupthanks .'</div><div id="returnVal" style="display:none;">true</div>';

            //Send verification email
            $m = new MailSender;
            $m->sendMail($newemail, $newuser, $newid, 'Verify');

        } else {
            //Failure
            mySqlErrors($response);

        }
    } else {
        //Validation error from empty form variables
        echo 'An error occurred on the form... try again';
    }

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
  echo "{$key} = {$value}\r\n";
}
};
```

To make it abundantly clear, my question remains why my added field isn't making it to the final PHP file.

Also to make clear, this code works perfectly without attempting to add an extra field. Tried and true, this code is functional. As soon as I attempt to add my name field, the code breaks.

Thank you for any help that can be provided.

Comment: your string concatenation for data in ajax feels wrong. rechecked?

Comment: I think you are missing one opening " in data of ajax. replace that with "newuser="+username+"&password1="+password+"&password2="+password2+"&email="+email+"&name="+name, and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made up a dummy test script based loosely upon what you have provided.

HINT when providing code - please specify the actual filename for each section.

This is a section of your "signup.js" file with your data definition commented out and the new one added.

A nicer way is to structure your data as shown below.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "createuser.php",
    // data: "newuser=" + username + & password1 = "+password+" & password2 = "+password2+" & email = "+email+" & name = "+name,
    data: {
        'newuser': username,
        'password1': password,
        'password2': password2,
        'email': email,
        'name': name
    },
```

With the code I ran up - I got it to var_dump($_POST) which displayed the POST data back on the form under the submit button. So that bit should work.

Give that a shot.

Below is the result I got back after entering the data into the form ( The results are the values I typed in for testing and I had removed your validation to get it out of the way )

```
array (size=5)
  'newuser' => string 'my username' (length=11)
  'password1' => string 'my password' (length=11)
  'password2' => string 'my password' (length=11)
  'email' => string 'my email' (length=8)
  'name' => string 'my name' (length=7)
```

Comment: This is a far superior way to structure my data and I will use this method from here on out! As well it resolved the issue with the POST. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Placeholder** are not "default values". You can't expect them to be sent as content. That's why you are getting a warning in PHP.

The other problem is your string concatenation: the quote is missing.

It should be `"newuser="+username+"&password1="+password` instead of your what you are currently having: `"newuser="+username+&password1="+password`
Note the quote before `&password1`.

You probably should get a better editor, because you should have caught this based on syntax highlighting.

---

That said, there are a lot of things wrong with this.

First of all, instead of using `uniqid(rand(), false)` for generating ID, you should be relying on MySQL's `AUTO_INCREMENT` feature.

Then there is you JS. Why are you using jQuery for this?! JS now has [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), which is superior to jQuery's approach. And there is [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) abstraction, that simplifies form handling.

```
document.querySelector('usersignup').addEventListener('submit', function (event){
    fetch('createuser.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: new FormData(event.target)
    }).then(function (response) {
        return resonse.text())
    }).then(function(html) {
        document.querySelector('#message').innerHTML = html;
    })
}, false);
```

Though, you will have to add a [polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) for compatibility with older IE versions.

Also ... what exactly is the point of sending the repeated password? You can compare them on JS side and only send one of them.

Comment: All of your statements make perfect sense, and I will update my code to better it. That being said I didn't write this code, this is based off of a cloned repo as stated earlier. I'm also going to suggest an edit to this persons repo. Thanks for the help!